# Efficiently transforming pandas dataframe column names into row values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with log data of a site key and then a key/value pair of event and timestamp. A pre-process delivers it as a pandas dataframe of indeterminable number of columns (could be 1-N), in which the column is the key and the value is the timestamp. I know this is a less-than ideal structure but I can't change it. What's an efficient way to operate on the the dataframe such that, for every key, I'm able to count non-null columns and identify the non-null values?

Here's hypothetical [raw data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/roablep/a11da82de18b14bd2c3c/raw/257f2fa7634002db267e2ef599d6e0cd330c1c72/Sourcedata):

```
KeyCol  ValCol1 ValCol2 ValCol3
A   ValCol1 ValCol2 nan
B   nan nan nan
C   ValCol1 nan ValCol3
D   nan ValCol2 nan
C   nan nan ValCol3
```

And here's the [desired output](https://gist.github.com/roablep/82fc0da73789b3663fe6):

```
KeyCol  Len Vals
A   2   [ValCol1, ValCol2]
B   0   []
C   2   [ValCol1, ValCol3]
D   1   [ValCol2]
```

Here's what I've done so far... but it seems inefficient. How would I optimize it?

```
import pandas as pd

def iterate_rows_for_nonnulls(df, grouper):
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)
    assert isinstance(grouper, (list, tuple))

    aggdic = {}
    for row, data in df.iterrows():
        key = tuple(data[grouper])
        nonnulls = data[~data.index.isin(grouper)]
        nonnulls = nonnulls[nonnulls.notnull()]
        data[data.notnull()]
        if key not in aggdic: 
            aggdic[key] = {}
            aggdic[key]['vals'] = nonnulls
        else:
            aggdic[key]['vals'] = aggdic[key]['vals'].append(nonnulls)

    for key, val in aggdic.iteritems():
        aggdic[key]['vals'] = aggdic[key]['vals'].unique()
        aggdic[key]['len'] = len(aggdic[key]['vals'])
    # Testing using [key for key in aggdic.iteritems() if aggdic[key[0]]['len']>0 ]
    return aggdic

def construct_df_from_nonnulls(aggdic):
    assert isinstance(aggdic, dict)
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(aggdic)).T

sourcedf = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/roablep/a11da82de18b14bd2c3c/raw/257f2fa7634002db267e2ef599d6e0cd330c1c72/Sourcedata', sep = "\t")
aggdic = iterate_rows_for_nonnulls(sourcedf, ['KeyCol'])
resultsdf = construct_df_from_nonnulls(aggdic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly -- it's weird to have column names being the same as the values of all the elements in those columns -- I think you can simply throw `groupby` at it after `melt`ing:

```
>>> d2 = pd.melt(df,id_vars="KeyCol")
>>> grouped = d2.groupby("KeyCol", as_index=False)["value"]
>>> dout = grouped.agg({"Len": "nunique", 
                        "Vals": lambda x: x.dropna().unique().tolist()})
>>> dout
  KeyCol                Vals  Len
0      A  [ValCol1, ValCol2]    2
1      B                  []    0
2      C  [ValCol1, ValCol3]    2
3      D           [ValCol2]    1
```

Reading the doc section on the [`split-apply-combine`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) pattern is highly recommended.

That said, note that putting non-scalar objects like lists in Series or DataFrames as elements is a recipe for headaches-- they're not really supported.  It can sometimes be useful as a temporary measure as an intermediate step, but you can't really do much with that Series after making it.